# Detect impossible data entry errors from repeated measures in data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to check huge databases with repeated measures of several variables of individuals. As I can have more than 3 million of observations, I would like to remove at least the data that I'm sure that are data entry errors.

**Continuous variables**

For example, focusing on the variable weight (e.g. dataframe below), I know that the individuals cannot reduce their weight more than 40% between one observation and the next one. How can I detect the observations that have a higher weight loss as in the third observation of the individual "2" which has reduced its weight from 30 grams to 3 grams.

**Categorical variables**

For example, regarding to the status of the individuals. One individual may be classified as 3 statuses (e.g "juvenile", "adult non breeder" or "adult breeder"; 1, 2 and 3 respectively). I know that one individual cannot become juvenile ("1") if it is adult ("2" or "3"), but it is possible a transition between 3-->2. In this particular case I would like to detect the observation 9 where the individual "3" has been classified as "juvenile" but in the previous observation was classified as "adult".

```
Individuals <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
Weight <- c(10, 14, 20, 15, 30, 3, 12, 34, 30)
Week <- rep(1:3, 3)
Status <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1)
df <- as.data.frame (cbind(Individuals, Weight, Week, Status))
df

        Individuals Weight Week Status
1           1     10    1      1
2           1     14    2      2
3           1     20    3      3
4           2     15    1      2
5           2     30    2      3
6           2      3    3      3
7           3     12    1      2
8           3     34    2      3
9           3     30    3      1
```

Do you know how can I solve these two kind of errors?

Comment: So, would you like to remove the specific rows of individuals 2 and 3, or every row of those individuals?

Comment: To detect the rows, later and depending each case I will decide to remove the row or every row of those individuals.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use the `data.table` package. I've had a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634025/changing-value-when-multiple-rows-columns-combined-do-not-meet-a-requirement) which required multiple lines for one mutation. However I don't have the skills to help you out here.

Comment: You'll get some great answers here. You can use `dplyr`, `data.table`, or base R. The main thing is to be able to create a list of issues you know they'll help you spot data entry errors and then try to imagine how they will look in the dataset and, finally, create the appropriate filters to flag them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
library(data.table)
  library(zoo)
  df <- data.table(df)
  # used to check percentage change in weight variable
  calcreduction <- function(x){
    res <- diff(x)/x[-length(x)]
    return(c(0,res))
  }
  # this will make it easy to get rid of values where WeightReduction < -.4

  #function used to assign combination type
  # you can have 11,12,13,22,23,32,33 or 21,31. The latter are "bad"
  getcomb <- function(x){
    res <- rbind(c(0,0),rollapply(x,2,paste))
    return(paste(res[,1],res[,2],sep=""))
  } 
  # this will make it easy to get rid of values where the Status change is no good

  # you can just pull the new vectors and then use logic
  # to decide what you want to do with these values
  res <- df[,list("WeightReduction"=calcreduction(Weight),
                  "StatusChange"=getcomb(Status),Weight,Week,Status),by=Individuals]

> res
   Individuals WeightReduction StatusChange Weight Week Status
1:           1       0.0000000           00     10    1      1
2:           1       0.4000000           12     14    2      2
3:           1       0.4285714           23     20    3      3
4:           2       0.0000000           00     15    1      2
5:           2       1.0000000           23     30    2      3
6:           2      -0.9000000           33      3    3      3
7:           3       0.0000000           00     12    1      2
8:           3       1.8333333           23     34    2      3
9:           3      -0.1176471           31     30    3      1
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description and based only on the "issues" you mentioned above try this:

```
Individuals <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
Weight <- c(10, 14, 20, 15, 30, 3, 12, 34, 30)
Week <- rep(1:3, 3)
Status <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1)
df <- as.data.frame (cbind(Individuals, Weight, Week, Status))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Individuals) %>%      ## for each individual
  mutate(WeightReduce = 1-Weight/dplyr::lag(Weight, default = Weight[1])) %>%  ## calculate the weight reduce (negative numbers here mean weight increase)
  ungroup() %>%                  ## forget the grouping
  mutate(flag = ifelse(WeightReduce >= 0.4 | dplyr::lag(Status, default = Status[1]) %in% 2:3 & Status == 1, 1, 0))  ## flag errors based on filters


#    Individuals Weight  Week Status WeightReduce  flag
#          (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl)        (dbl) (dbl)
# 1           1     10     1      1    0.0000000     0
# 2           1     14     2      2   -0.4000000     0
# 3           1     20     3      3   -0.4285714     0
# 4           2     15     1      2    0.0000000     0
# 5           2     30     2      3   -1.0000000     0
# 6           2      3     3      3    0.9000000     1
# 7           3     12     1      2    0.0000000     0
# 8           3     34     2      3   -1.8333333     0
# 9           3     30     3      1    0.1176471     1
```

Comment: It works perfectly, the unique thing is that I have had to change the 'dplyr::lag' by 'stats::lag'.

Comment: Yes it works using `stats::lag`. If I use 'dplyr::lag' it gives the error: "`lag` is not an exported object from `namespace:dplyr`"

Comment: Interesting. I have the opposite behaviour. Doesn't work with `stats::lag`. Could be a R or `dplyr` version you're using. Can you try just `lag` then? Might work for you...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `data.table` package to compute the rate of weight change and the juvenile anomaly, and then filter on these two criteria:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,c('continuous', 'categorical'):=list(
              c(0,diff(Weight)/head(Weight, -1)),  # rate of weight change per individual
              Status==1 & c(F,diff(Status)<0)),Individuals][ 
          continuous>=-0.4 & !categorical,][]

#   Individuals Weight Week Status    change continuous categorical
#1:           1     10    1      1 0.0000000  0.0000000       FALSE
#2:           1     14    2      2 0.4000000  0.4000000       FALSE
#3:           1     20    3      3 0.4285714  0.4285714       FALSE
#4:           2     15    1      2 0.0000000  0.0000000       FALSE
#5:           2     30    2      3 1.0000000  1.0000000       FALSE
#6:           3     12    1      2 0.0000000  0.0000000       FALSE
#7:           3     34    2      3 1.8333333  1.8333333       FALSE
```

Comment: It detects perfectly the "wrong" observations, but I would like that the function would mantain the wrong observation for checking if I have to remove exclusively the observation or the entire individual.

Comment: In thos case you can remove the last line of my code (which filters) and you're done ;)